# How to trim space from right side of string?

Tags: ms-access, split, ms-access-2007, vba, trim

I am importing one table from excel. One of the column has some space it seems.
So for example the String is A = abc/xyz/rpw

Now I am using split

```
sSplit = Split(A, "/", -1, vbBinaryCompare)
```

Inthis case sSplit(2) which is rpw has a space at the end and I am not able to remove it even after trimming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Trim(sSplit(2))` doesn't eliminate the trailing space, there is a chance that string ends with  a character or characters which look like a space but are actually something else.

Use the `Asc()` function to determine the ASCII value of the right-most character.  A space character is ASCII 32.

```vb
Debug.Print Asc(Right(sSplit(2), 1))
```

Also verify the number of characters.  If it's greater than 4, *"rpw"* is followed by more than one character.

```vb
Debug.Print Len(sSplit(2))
```

In a comment, you reported the problem character is a line feed character, ASCII 10.  You can use the `Replace()` function to discard all line feeds from the string, not just when the line feed is the last character.  Or, if there may be line feeds within the string and you want those kept, you can use `Left()` with the length of the string minus one to discard only the last character.

Here is an Immediate window session which may make it clearer.

```vb
' this variable is a proxy for the 3rd element of your array
sSplit_2 = "rpw" & Chr(10)
? Len(sSplit_2)
 4 
? ">" & sSplit_2 & "<"
>rpw
<
' use Replace to discard every line feed from the string
? ">" & Replace(sSplit_2, Chr(10), "") & "<"
>rpw<
' extract all but the last character of the string
? ">" & Left(sSplit_2, Len(sSplit_2) -1) & "<"
>rpw<
```

If it's more convenient, you could discard the trailing line feed from your *"A"* string before you `Split` it.

Comment: Yes, the length is 4 instead of 3...but what can be a solution...i cannot find any space in the excel sheet either.....

Comment: As I said I am getting the data from a excel sheet...Now the excel sheet has many rows and each have different values like I have mentioned...Currently I am facing problem with only one row. So If I get only the left split then there may be other words which may be longer and will also be shortened....I hope you got my problem....The solution I am looking for is how to get rid of these extra spaces or reason of why they are there

Comment: What did `Asc()` give you for the ASCII value of that trailing character?

Comment: Yes I got the ASC value of 10..which is a NL Line feed I guess.

Comment: I added two methods to get rid of that character.  See whether either of those fits your context.

Comment: I tried replace in the code but somehow its not working,so I worked the table to update it and replaced the data in there..that method worked fine...